# Renaming TValue Array Type

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have been experiencing an oddity involving renaming TValue array type like;

```
TValueArray1 := TArray <TValue>;
TValueArray2 := Array of TValue;
```

I mean to say that shouldn't they behave similarly? 
I have a method which has a constant open array of TValue as argument but when I replace it with any TValueArray, the compiler starts expecting ordinal values, why?

For example, works correctly;

```
// G1 - TGUID; B1 - TBytes; I1 - Integer; S1 - String

procedure TAgBuffer.Add ( const AData: Array of TValue );
TAgBuffer.Add ( [(TValue.From <TGUID> ( G1 )), TValue.From <TBytes> ( B1 ), I1, S1] );
```

But after replacing 'Array of TValue' with any TValueArray gives the following compiler errors:-

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(44): E2001 Ordinal type required // for G1
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(44): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'TValue' // for B1
```

Comment: There is a difference between open arrays and typed arrays.

Comment: You cannot use open array constructor syntax (the brackets) for dynamic array parameters - see http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=93549

Comment: It would be great, if that feature gets included in future release though...

Comment: Why? There's no need for a new feature. Simply use open array parameters.

Comment: I want to return an argument array of TValues from a similar method, while not declaring the array or assigning the individual TValues to it before the call. It would be a simple assignment.

Comment: If you cannot use open arrays, for instance a return value, then use generic array `TArray<T>` since it has much better type compatibility properties than old school dynamic array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The problem with passing open array arguments is that you cannot work with them as easy as you can with TArray<T>.

Comment: @StefanGlienke It all depends. The problem with declaring parameters of type `TArray<T>` is that there are fewer things that you can pass at the call site. Open arrays make the function more widely callable. So long as you can do what you need in the implementation of the function, open arrays are to be preferred. If the implementation becomes hard, then the balance changes. What operations are you thinking of that cannot be performed on open arrays that can be performed on dynamic arrays?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You cannot store them in a variable/field with a simple assignment for later use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking why these two are different:

```
procedure foo1(const a: array of Integer);
procedure foo2(const a: TArray<Integer>);
```

The reason is that the parameter of `foo1` is an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Open_Array_Parameters) and the parameter of `foo2` is a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays). And they are simply different beasts. It is really important that you understand that an open array parameter is different from a dynamic array.

My rule of thumb here is that you should use open array parameters where possible. The reason being is that they accept the widest variety of possible actual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that explains in details the difference between open arrays and dynamic arrays

http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html